# SVG only (no JS) - line/path animation

Tags: css, svg

I can't think my way through this one... I can't really add mark-up in a project, only CSS (for many boring reasons with who I'm collaborating remotely with).

The end client wants a loading animation of their logo path being drawn but not linear, more ease-in-out (slow-fast-slow) sort of thing. To illustrate what I mean, see jsfiddle I've done: https://jsfiddle.net/tobzzzz/djf7oth2/ (their logo is a bit like a speech mark, I've done a circle for ease for the demo).

The logo will sit on top of an image background, not a white/solid colour background, so my fiddle solution won't work of two circles layered. I added light grey background to demonstrate how it doesn't work.

The IDEAL solution would be SVG only (using SVG animation not CSS animation), I'd then convert it into data and put it as a background-image.

If it can't be done with SVG animation only, I'd like to know if it can be done with SVG and CSS combo. But it absolutely 100% cannot be JS.

Any good ideas?

```css
body {
  background: #eee
}

.black {
  stroke-dasharray: 350;
  stroke-dashoffset: 350;
  animation: dash 4s linear infinite;
}

.white {
  stroke-dasharray: 350;
  stroke-dashoffset: 350;
  animation: dash2 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="path" width="84" height="84" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path class="black" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M 80.889194,41.80541 C 80.889194,63.45198 63.341174,81 41.694594,81 20.048024,81 2.5,63.45198 2.5,41.80541 2.5,20.158827 20.048024,2.61081 41.694594,2.61081 c 21.64658,0 39.1946,17.548017 39.1946,39.1946 z"/>
      <path class="white" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" d="M 80.889194,41.80541 C 80.889194,63.45198 63.341174,81 41.694594,81 20.048024,81 2.5,63.45198 2.5,41.80541 2.5,20.158827 20.048024,2.61081 41.694594,2.61081 c 21.64658,0 39.1946,17.548017 39.1946,39.1946 z"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to animate the `stroke-dasharray`, not only the `stroke-dashoffset`. You can add multiple numbers to the value of the dasharray, defining alternating lengths of dashes and gaps. So, if you circle with `r="40"` has a circumference of `251,4`,

- `0 251.4` is a stroke of 0 length and a gap around the whole circumference
- `125.7 125.7` is a half-circle stroke and a half-circle gap
- and then reduce the stroke length again

At the same time, move the start of the stroke around the circle by animating the offset.

There is a lot of finetuning you can do with other intermediate values, by distributing the keyTimes differently and with easing functions. Here is a basic variant with linear animations:

```html
<svg width="84" height="84">
    <circle r="40" cx="42" cy="42" style="fill: none;stroke: black;stroke-width: 4;">
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                 keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0 251.4;125.7 125.7;0 251.4" />
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                 keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0;-100;-251.4" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perhaps they should give you an SVG degree - standing for Seriously Very Good. Great answer and perfectly explained - thank you.

Comment: for my demo I used a circle (nice and easy). In real life the logo is a path that looks like a speech mark. How do I determine by end point (251.4 being the circles end point in example you gave)?

Comment: For a path with `id="myPath"`, `document.querySelector('#myPath').getTotalLength()` You need JS here, but only once, executed on the console.

Comment: So easy when you know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape makes it easy to modify a path and to save it.
Below the svg includes **from** and **to** paths.
The tag **animate** after a 1 second delay makes the eye blinks twice and then stops:

```html
<svg style="vertical-align:middle;opacity:0.7" 
  width="13" height="13" 
  viewBox="0 0 12 12" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="glass_1" d="m6 3c2.58 0 4.23 2.07 4.84 3-.62.93-2.26 3-4.84 3s-4.23-2.07-4.84-3c.62-.93 2.26-3 4.84-3m0-1c-4 0-6 4-6 4s2 4 6 4 6-4 6-4-2-4-6-4zm0 2a2 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 -2-2z"
 fill="green">
</path>
    <animate xlink:href="#glass_1" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" 
from="m6 3c2.58 0 4.23 2.07 4.84 3-.62.93-2.26 3-4.84 3s-4.23-2.07-4.84-3c.62-.93 2.26-3 4.84-3m0-1c-4 0-6 4-6 4s2 4 6 4 6-4 6-4-2-4-6-4zm0 2a2 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 -2-2z" 
to="m6.1 5.9c2.6 0 3-0.019 4.7 0.092-1.4 0.58-2.2 0.59-4.7 0.59s-3.8 0.0053-4.9-0.59c1.2-0.069 2.4-0.092 5-0.092m0-1c-4 0-6.1 1.1-6.1 1.1s2.1 1.6 6.1 1.6c4 0 5.9-1.6 5.9-1.6s-1.9-1.1-5.9-1.1zm-0.13-0.91c-1.8 0-2.7 2.2-1.4 3.4s3.4 0.37 3.4-1.4c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2z" 
  begin="1s;op.end" 
  repeatCount="2" 
  dur="0.5s">
</animate>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

have you looked at this?

https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus-instant/

You can drag in any SVG and it has limited animation capabilities automatically.

Comment: It's a nice tool to build something similar to what I've already built, for those who don't know how to do that. It's not a solution to my question.